# how to find linkbutton id in javascript,

Tags: asp.net, javascript

my linkbutton is in datalist, this datalist is in panel, this panel is in ajax updatepanel

if linkbutton is not selected then need to alert a message...

how can i achieve this...

Comment: That, and you may need to show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve this, here is an example:

```
aspx:
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" OnClientClick="fireMyClick(this)"></asp:LinkButton>
js:
function fireMyClick(lnk)
{
    alert(lnk.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
page.findcontrol(panlid).findcontrol(datalistid).findcontrol(linkbutonid)
```

i wrote code like this....